In clang-format, is there any way to add line break before brace in array initialization?
I would like Allman style and break before brace;
int array[3] =
{
    0,
    1,
    2,
};

but it will always like this:
int array[3] = {
    0,
    1,
    2,
};

Also there is no such option in BraceWrapping.
Anyone has some idea to add newline before brace of array initializer?

Set BreakBeforeBraces: Allman -> Not working

Set BreakBeforeBraces: Custom and every usable element of BraceWrapping to true


